# Error: *** Deployment Failed *** "Migrations" -- Returned error: no pending block

Tags: truffle-test

When i run "truffle test" in VS on my basic helloworld smart contract, i get the error message:

"Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- Returned error: no pending block."

Anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check in the truffle/migrations that you have correctly written the deployment of the contract for example :

```
// Help Truffle find `TruffleTutorial.sol` in the `/contracts` directory
const TruffleTutorial = artifacts.require("MyToken");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // Command Truffle to deploy the Smart Contract
  deployer.deploy(TruffleTutorial, "MyToken", "TKN", 10000, "DEPLOYER_ADDR");
};
```

Then check that in the truffle truffle.config you initialized the host, port and network id(uncomment) and change the port to your ganache listening port :
you can find your ganache listening port in ganache server settings.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
     development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. However i now get the below pop up...Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


  0 passing (1ms)

Comment: Is that normal?

Comment: Thats because you dont have any 
```
contract('ContractToken', (accounts) => {
    it('ecrecover result matches address', async function() {
         // do things  
    }
}
```
Have a look at this maybe it will help you.
https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript/

Comment: Awesome thanks managed to sort it out. For anyone else reading this, this is the correct testing format and syntax: const HelloWorld = artifacts.require('HelloWorld')

contract('HelloWorld', () => {

    it('should return hello world', async() => {
        const helloWorld = await HelloWorld.deployed();
        const result = await helloWorld.hello();
        assert(result === 'Hello World');


    });
});